# Wordpress PHP Check if a product category has child categories (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

the situation is that when on a product category which is parent category and has children I should list the children categories of that parent, that is the first part of the code and works as it should then the "elseif" part is the issue. I need to display child categories of a parent category of that child when on the child category. That also works, but I cannot seem to find out solution that when a person is on a category which itself is a parent (without child categories) that it shows all top level (main) categories. Actually, that also does work with the "else" part of the code, but I don't know which condition to put to the "elseif" block, so that is recognizes that..

Point is: "elseif" condition part I cannot solve so that if on a product category which is parent and there is no children that the conditions returns false so it can go to "else" block and execute code.

Thank you for time time :)

````
<?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$parent = $queried_object->term_id;
$parent_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'child_of' => $parent ) );
$child_terms    = get_term_children ( $queried_object->term_id, 'product_cat' );
$based_term     = (is_wp_error($child_terms) || empty($child_terms)) ? get_term ( $queried_object->parent, 'product_cat' ) : $queried_object;


if ( $parent_categories && ! is_wp_error( $parent_categories ) ) {

    echo '<ul class="product-category-listing" >';

    $term = get_term( $parent_categories, 'product_cat' );

    foreach($parent_categories as $parent_category) :

    $term = get_term( $parent_category, 'product_cat' );


    echo '<li class="product-category-title" >';
    echo '<a class="product-category-title-btn" href="'.get_term_link($term).'" >';
    echo $term->name;
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';

    endforeach;

} elseif ( $parent_categories !== false ) {
    
    $args = array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'hide_empty' => true,
          'parent'        => $based_term->term_id,
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
      );
  $product_cat = get_terms( $args );
    
  foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
  {
      

  echo '<ul class="product-category-listing '.$parent_product_cat->slug.'">
        <li class="product-category-title"> 
            <a href="'.get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id).'" class="product-category-title-btn">'.$parent_product_cat->name.' 
            <svg width="8" height="12" viewBox="0 0 8 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M7 6.53125C7.28125 6.25 7.28125 5.78125 7 5.46875L2.75 1.21875C2.4375 0.9375 1.96875 0.9375 1.6875 1.21875L0.96875 1.9375C0.6875 2.25 0.6875 2.71875 0.96875 3L4 6.03125L0.96875 9.03125C0.6875 9.3125 0.6875 9.78125 0.96875 10.0938L1.6875 10.7812C1.96875 11.0938 2.4375 11.0938 2.75 10.7812L7 6.53125Z" fill="#1ABFDF"/>
</svg>
</a>
        <ul class="product-category-single">';
  $child_args = array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'hide_empty' => true,
              'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id,
              'orderby' => 'title',
              'order' => 'ASC',
          );
  $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
  foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
  {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</a></li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>
      </li>
    </ul>';
  }
    
} 

else {
    $args = array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'hide_empty' => true,
          'parent'        => 0,
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
      );
  $product_cat = get_terms( $args );
    
  foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
  {

  echo '<ul class="product-category-listing '.$parent_product_cat->slug.'">
        <li class="product-category-title">
            <a href="'.get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id).'" class="product-category-title-btn">'.$parent_product_cat->name.' 
            <svg width="8" height="12" viewBox="0 0 8 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M7 6.53125C7.28125 6.25 7.28125 5.78125 7 5.46875L2.75 1.21875C2.4375 0.9375 1.96875 0.9375 1.6875 1.21875L0.96875 1.9375C0.6875 2.25 0.6875 2.71875 0.96875 3L4 6.03125L0.96875 9.03125C0.6875 9.3125 0.6875 9.78125 0.96875 10.0938L1.6875 10.7812C1.96875 11.0938 2.4375 11.0938 2.75 10.7812L7 6.53125Z" fill="#1ABFDF"/>
</svg>

</a>
        <ul class="product-category-single">';
  $child_args = array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'hide_empty' => true,
              'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id,
              'orderby' => 'title',
              'order' => 'ASC',
          );
  $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
  foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
  {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</a></li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>
      </li>
    </ul>';
  }
};
?>```
````

Comment: If `$parent->parent` is `0`, it is a parent. And if it doesn't have any child categories, then `get_term_children` should have returned an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Bascially update is that using Grid Builder Facets is much better and easier:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).